# How to cluster X to maximize explained variance in Y?

Tags: cluster-analysis

This is a problem I've encountered more than once, and I have pseudo-solution in mind but it's more or less a Monte Carlo method rather than anything clever.

What I'm trying to do is essentially convert a continuous variable into a categorical variable in such a way that each category has a significantly different mean in the response variable.

So let's say I am trying to model rates of depression against Age Groups. In my model, I want to have up to N Age Groups, and the bounds for each group can be arbitrarily sized (5-10, 11-27, 28-30, 31-64...etc). The question is, how to choose the bounds such that with N groups, the explained variance in depression rates can be maximized?

```
# Monte Carlo approach using iris dataset as an example
n_clust = 5

best_bounds = rep(0, n_clust)
best_groups = NULL
bestSSE = Inf

X_var = iris$Petal.Length
Y_var = iris$Sepal.Width

min_x = min(X_var)
max_x = max(X_var)
range_x = max_x - min_x

for (i in 1:10000){

  b = sort(runif(n_clust-1))
  b = cumsum(b / sum(b))
  bounds = min_x + b * range_x
  groups = cut(X_var, breaks = c(-Inf,bounds,Inf))

  model = lm(Y_var~groups)
  SSE = sum(model$residuals^2)
  if (SSE < bestSSE){
    print(SSE)
    best_bounds = bounds
    best_groups = groups
    bestSSE = SSE
  }
}

g = aggregate(Y_var, list(best_groups), mean)
names(g) = c("Cluster", "y_mean")
g$Cluster=c(best_bounds)

plot(X_var, Y_var, col='blue', pch=20)
abline(lm(Y_var~X_var), col='darkgray', lty=2)

for (i in 1:(nrow(g))){
  x0 = ifelse(i == 1, min_x-max_x, g[i-1,"Cluster"])
  x1 = ifelse(i < nrow(g), g[i,"Cluster"], 2*max_x)
  segments(x0,g[i,"y_mean"],x1,g[i,"y_mean"], col='red')
}

R_cont = summary(lm(Y_var~X_var))$r.squared
R_cat = summary(lm(Y_var~best_groups))$r.squared
title(paste("R^2:", round(R_cont,4),"vs",round(R_cat,4)))
```

[image: Cluster X on Y]

Note: I don't care about interpretation, only predictive ability.

Answer (score 0):

I would not look at this from a clustering perspective. Instead, treat it as an optimization problem. Then do gradient descent to optimize, or any other search.

Another option would be **piecewise linear regression**, but you want a "piecewise constant regression" actually.

Comment: True, it is actually an optimization problem. I started to see it that way shortly after having made this post. Any ideas on how I might be able implement this kind of approach in R and/or python? I can't really see how to define the problem thats trying to be solved (the main complication being that x values need to be assigned to bins somehow).

And yeah, actually the idea is to create an automatic piecewise regression using this approach. Its just choosing the correct bins that is difficult!

Comment: I think I found a good solution that I'm happy with!

sol=optim(rep(0.5,n_clust), sse_loss, lower=rep(0,n_clust), upper=rep(1,n_clust), method="L-BFGS-B")

Comment: @Corpsecreate can you elaborate a bit on your solution from May 14, 2017. I have a similar problem i'm trying to solve.

Comment: Hey mate. I don't recall my solution from back then, but more recently I've used a decision tree for this problem. Set the number of leaves to equal the number of clusters, then use the leaf nodes as clusters. It's a rather neat trick, and you can also force the size of each cluster to be above a minimum threshold using min_leaf_size.